# Can't connect to the internet via Windows 8.1 - Ubuntu works fine

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8, internet, windows-8.1

I have Ubuntu and Windows 8.1 installed on separate physical disks. When I start my computer I get to choose which one I want to enter.

When I enter Ubuntu, I can access the internet just fine, but when I go to Windows 8.1, I cannot access the internet. I have tried disabling the Firewall, uninstalling the antivirus etc., but it simply wont work. I'm also unable to download any update - so my web browsers are not faulty or something.

How do I troubleshoot this issue? It's not like the internet icon near the clock is showing the little exclamation mark - it appears to be connected just fine. The troubleshooter doesn't say there's a problem either.

How can I fix this problem?

P.S: My connection is wired and it worked well before installing Ubuntu.

Comment: Have you installed the Windows 8.1 compatible wireless device drivers?

Comment: They were there. The internet worked just fine before installing Ubuntu. Then I haven't had used Windows 8.1 for a few days and when I got back in the internet wouldn't work. I also have a wired connection, not wireless.

Comment: The installing of Ubuntu didn't break your internet.  Verify the drivers again

Comment: What should I check there? No missing drivers are showing. What exactly should I do?